# Docker: Passing Env variables for Cloud Code to Parse-Server and Parse-Dashboard

Tags: node.js, docker, parse-platform, docker-compose

I am trying to use following parseplatform images from docker hub instead of creating my own and wondering how to go about passing additional variables for -

1. S3 Adapter for AWS S3
2. Mailgun Adapter for Email
3. Twilio for Send SMS
4. Add custom location for Cloud Code config as ENV var

```
     version: '3'
        services:
            parse:
                image: parseplatform/parse-server
                ports:
                    - 1337:1337
                environment:
                    - PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID=
                    - PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY=
                    - PARSE_SERVER_FILE_KEY=
                    - PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI=""
            dashboard:
                image: parseplatform/parse-dashboard
                ports:
                    - 4040:4040
                environment:
                    - PARSE_DASHBOARD_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:1337/parse
                    - PARSE_DASHBOARD_APP_ID=
                    - PARSE_DASHBOARD_MASTER_KEY=
                    - PARSE_DASHBOARD_APP_NAME=
                    - PARSE_DASHBOARD_ALLOW_INSECURE_HTTP=1
                    - PARSE_DASHBOARD_USER_ID=user
                    - PARSE_DASHBOARD_USER_PASSWORD=
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to pass in the cloud code but now trying to understand how to tackle 3rd party libraries like Twilio -

```
            - PARSE_SERVER_CLOUD=/parse-server/cloud/main.js
        volumes:
            - ./parse-server/cloud:/parse-server/cloud
```